# Two congruence. Are they true?

Tags: congruences

Let $p$ be prime, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $l \in \mathbb{N}$

The first one:
$$ n \neq pl \implies \forall k\in \mathbb{N} \ \  n^{\phi (p^k)} \equiv 1 \pmod p. \\
$$
And the second one:
$$ (1+n)^p = 1+ n \mod p. $$

Are they true?

Comment: You could check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem.

Comment: Isn't $n^{\phi(p^k)}$ equal to $n^{P^k-k}$?

Comment: BTW, did you mean $(1+n)^p\equiv1+n\pmod{p}$ in the second statement? Otherwise, it's obviously false with various counterexamples.

Comment: I don't see counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

As $\varphi(p^k)=p^{k-1}(p-1)$ and $n^{p-1}\equiv 1 \mod p$ for all $\not\equiv 0 \mod p$ (Little Fermat), we have $$n^{\varphi(p^k)}=\bigl(n^{p-1}\bigr)^{p^{k-1}}\equiv 1 \mod p.$$

For the second congruence, it is even more general:
$$(n+n')^p\equiv n^p+n'^p \mod p$$
because one shows that, if $p$ is prime, all binomial coefficients $\displaystyle\binom pk$ are divisible by $p\,$ if $\,0<k<p$. So 
$$(1+n)^p\equiv 1+n^p \equiv 1+n $$
by Little Fermat again : $\,n^{p-1}\equiv 1 \mod p\Rightarrow n^p\equiv n$  for all $n\not\equiv 0 \mod p$, and $n^p\equiv n\,$ *also* if $n\equiv 0\mod p$.